# how to get double footer?

Tags: html, css

I want my footer to fit in nicely in two lines.but what I have doesn't stretch enough and the bottom should be white but shown as black background.

```
    <footer>
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="inner-wrap clearfix">
      <div class="section about">

      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom-footer">
    <div class = "inner-wrap clearfix">
      <p class="fotter-quote">
        <em>
          <i class = "fa fa-quote-left"></i>just live your life<i class = "fa fa-quote-right"></i>
        </em>

      </p>
    </div>
    <p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

and this is my css

```
footer #footer {
  width:100%;
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 60px 0px;
}

footer #bottom-footer{
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: how does your CSS look like?

Comment: Its all in the css. Write your css properly for bottom-footer and it will work just fine. Posst your css here so that we could help better.

Comment: you should review your HTML, there are unclosed tags (p, div)

Comment: You have a different problem with the entire css - you can see that the top footer looks different too. Check this demo which take the original css and it's look OK. http://jsbin.com/qihusi/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont Know What is Very much difficult in this

Here is The [Code](https://jsfiddle.net/dineshkanivu/1vk6qbru/)

HTML

```
<div class="content">
Here is the Content
</div>

<footer>
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="inner-wrap clearfix">
      <div class="section about">
Footer 1
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>



   <div id="bottom-footer">
    <div class = "inner-wrap clearfix">
     Footer 2
    </div>

  </div>

</footer>
```

CSS

```
body{margin:0;padding:0}
.content{background:white; width:100%; height:700px}
#footer{    background: #2c3036;width:100%; height:300px}
#bottom-footer{background: #16a085;height:40px}
```

Comment: hello but with this my footers arent' stretched tho, I want then to be stretched in width. and the bottom needs to be stretched too. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change the #bottom-footer to match the #footer

```
footer #bottom-footer{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 60px 0px;
}
```

That might get you a #bottom-footer similar to #footer.

Edit: Just noticed you have not closed the div tag `<div class="inner-wrap clearfix">`

Comment: hello but with this my footers arent' stretched tho, I want then to be stretched in width. and the bottom needs to be stretched too. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `div` tag.

It should look like this:

```
<footer>
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="inner-wrap clearfix">
      <div class="section about">

      </div> <!--- Missing tag --->
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom-footer">
    <div class = "inner-wrap clearfix">
      <p class="fotter-quote">
        <em>
          <i class = "fa fa-quote-left"></i>just live your life<i class = "fa fa-quote-right"></i>
        </em>

      </p>
    </div>
    <p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Also, here is some CSS you will need to add to get the result you are looking for:

```
footer #bottom-footer{
 padding:5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/km8erkyj/2/)

Comment: hello but with this my footers arent' stretched tho, I want then to be stretched in width. and the bottom needs to be stretched too. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: add `footer{width:100%;}` to your css

Answer (score 0):

try with below code it may help you.

```css
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

footer{
     background-color: #1fa67a;
    border-top: 1px solid #1b926c;
 font-family : open sans;
}

.widget h3{
  margin : 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff; 
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
}

.widget ul{
  margin-left : -25px;
}
.widget ul li {
  list-style-type : none;   
}

.widget ul li a{
   padding-left: 5px;
   color: #fff;
   text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
}

.copyright{
  background-color : #000;
  padding : 5px;
  color : #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<footer>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-md-3">
      <div class="widget">
        <h3>Products</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Product1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Product2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Product3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Product4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Product5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-md-3">
      <div class="widget">
        <h3>Products</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Product1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Product2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Product3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Product4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Product5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-md-3">
      <div class="widget">
        <h3>Products</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Product1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Product2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Product3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Product4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Product5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-md-3">
      <div class="widget">
        <h3>partners</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" target="_self"><img src="https://s3.buysellads.com/1298241/309950-1454187271.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="copyright">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         © 2016
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <span class="pull-right">powerd by <a>xyz.com</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</footer>
```